# Python - Add a new row to a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I am appending new data to a csv file, it adds the information. The next time it added it, it misses a row.
How can I make it not miss out a row? (So it appends straight below the last piece of data?)

When I open the file on Excel I it comes up as:
Laura 99

(extra row)

Laura 99

Instead of:

Laura 99

Laura 99

[Notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBzQY.png)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gToCZ.png)

```
import csv

with open ("scoreboard.csv", "a") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(["Laura", "99"])
print ("The New score has been added to the score sheet")
```

Comment: This code works fine when I run it.

Comment: Did you make sure to close any previous `open` calls?

Comment: When you run the code twice is the data underneath the other or does it miss a line? I open it in Excel and there is an extra row, which I don't want.

Comment: if you run it twice then you should get two rows. What did you expected? What do you get when you run it ? Show your file in question.

Comment: I don't get the extra row after running twice. Try opening it in notepad or something similar instead. What do you see?

Comment: I have add  a notepad and excel screenshot/link - you can see what I get.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Explain exactly what is your goal and what you are getting instead, with examples from your console output.

Comment: I've just tried with Notepad and Excel and don't get extra lines

Comment: Are you on a windows or linux or mac machine? That could be making a difference

Comment: Windows machine